# classX' does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I have `myclassA` and `myClassB`. I want to pass a `ClassA` object into `ClassB`'s constructor. therefore I include `A`'s header into `B` and B's header into `A`, but I get this error

`'myclassB' does not name a type`

Here is the code that I simplified:

**myclassa.h**

```
#ifndef XMLHANDLER_H
#define XMLHANDLER_H
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "myclassb.h"

class myclassA{
public:
    myclassA();

private:
    myclassB *mb;
};
#endif // XMLHANDLER_H
```

**myclassb.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H
#include "myclassa.h"

class myclassB{
public:
    myclassB(myclassA *newclass);
    ~myclassB();
};
#endif // CLASSB_H
```

**myclassa.cpp**

```
#include "myclassa.h"

myclassA::myclassA(){}
```

**myclassb.cpp**

```
#include "myclassb.h"

myclassB::myclassB(myclassA *newclass)
{
    //do something
}
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: myclassb.h should not `#include "myclassa.h"` and should just contain a forward declaration of `myclassA` since itt only uses a pointer and does not need anything other than the type of A declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `class myclassB;` in `myclassa.h`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to include header myclassB in header myclassA

Or you can create a separate header that will contain declarations

class MyClassA;
class MyClassB;

and then include this header in other two.